# Why do I get 'missing keyword' for this query?

Tags: oracle

```
Select A.Smscid,
       A.Delivery_Date,
       A.Type,
       A.End_Delivery,
       A.Volume,
       (Case When A.Type='Transactional' And A.End_Delivery=B.Operator 
             Then (A.Volume*B.Onnet_Trans_Cost)) As "COST",
 From Telco_Success a,operators_cost b;
```

I am getting missing keyword error:

Comment: 1. `Case` statement has to have `End`. 2) remove comma after `As "COST"` or add another column name after `As "COST",`

Comment: No join between the tables?

Answer (score 5):

Untested, but you seem to be missing the `End` keyword on your `Case` statement. Also you seem to have a comma after "COST" which is not needed.

```
Select A.Smscid,
       A.Delivery_Date,
       A.Type,
       A.End_Delivery,
       A.Volume,
       (Case When A.Type='Transactional' And A.End_Delivery=B.Operator 
             Then (A.Volume*B.Onnet_Trans_Cost) End) As "COST"
 From Telco_Success a,operators_cost b;
```